# Turn URL into String (decode URL)

Tags: python, url

I have a website looks like this:

```
http://abc.com/hsdl-3201%23008-lite-on-12275800/hsdl-3201%23008-lite-on-12275800
```

Clearly, because there are some weird characters that don't fit into the URL format and they have been encoded into %20 like characters.. I am wondering how could I easily decode that back to python string that contains the original character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

Python 2

```
from urllib import unquote
```

Then

```
unquote('http://abc.com/hsdl-3201%23008-lite-on-12275800/hsdl-3201%23008-lite-on-12275800')
#>>> 'http://abc.com/hsdl-3201#008-lite-on-12275800/hsdl-3201#008-lite-on-12275800'
```

Also check `unquote_plus` if you're doing this for parsing forms, where spaces are encoded to `"+"` and thus need to be decoded.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

From the docs:

> urllib.unquote(string) Replace %xx escapes by their single-character
>   equivalent.
>
> Example: `unquote('/%7Econnolly/')` yields `'/~connolly/'`.